# Finetune LlaMA 7B model using Pytorch Lightning Framework

Tags: nlp, pytorch-lightning, llama

**`Need Expert help to solve this issue. LLaMA 7B model for sentiment classification with instructional Finetuning.`**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer, LlamaForCausalLM, AdamW
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule, Trainer, seed_everything
from datasets import load_dataset
import pandas as pd
import json

seed_everything(42)

DEVICE = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class SentimentDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = self.data[idx]
        prompt = f"""Below is an instruction that describes a task, paired with an input that provides further context. Write a response that appropriately completes the request.  # noqa: E501
        ### Instruction:
        {item["instruction"]}
        ### Input:
        {item["input"]}
        ### Response:
        {item["output"]}"""
        return prompt

class SentimentClassifier(LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, base_model, learning_rate=2e-5):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_model = base_model
        self.tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(base_model)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.base_model.config.hidden_size, 3)
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        outputs = self.base_model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        last_hidden_state = outputs.last_hidden_state
        logits = self.classifier(last_hidden_state[:, 0, :])
        return logits

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids = batch["input_ids"].to(self.device)
        attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"].to(self.device)
        labels = batch["labels"].to(self.device)
        logits = self(input_ids, attention_mask)
        loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(logits, labels)
        self.log("train_loss", loss)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        input_ids = batch["input_ids"].to(self.device)
        attention_mask = batch["attention_mask"].to(self.device)
        labels = batch["labels"].to(self.device)
        logits = self(input_ids, attention_mask)
        loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(logits, labels)
        self.log("val_loss", loss)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
        return optimizer

    def collate_fn(self, batch):
        encoding = self.tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
            batch,
            padding="longest",
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        )
        return {
            "input_ids": encoding["input_ids"].squeeze(),
            "attention_mask": encoding["attention_mask"].squeeze(),
            "labels": encoding["input_ids"].squeeze()
        }

train = load_dataset("json", data_files="alpaca-bitcoin-sentiment-dataset_train.json")
validation = load_dataset("json", data_files="alpaca-bitcoin-sentiment-dataset_test.json")

train_dataset = SentimentDataset(train)
val_dataset = SentimentDataset(validation)

LEARNING_RATE = 2e-5
BATCH_SIZE = 8

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

from peft import (
    LoraConfig,
    get_peft_model,
    get_peft_model_state_dict,
    prepare_model_for_int8_training,
)

BASE_MODEL = "decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf"
 
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    BASE_MODEL,
    load_in_8bit=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map=0,
)
 
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(BASE_MODEL)
 
tokenizer.pad_token_id = (
    0  # unk. we want this to be different from the eos token
)
tokenizer.padding_side = "left"

LORA_R = 8
LORA_ALPHA = 16
LORA_DROPOUT= 0.05
LORA_TARGET_MODULES = [
    "q_proj",
    "v_proj",
]
 
model = prepare_model_for_int8_training(model)
config = LoraConfig(
    r=LORA_R,
    lora_alpha=LORA_ALPHA,
    target_modules=LORA_TARGET_MODULES,
    lora_dropout=LORA_DROPOUT,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
)
model = get_peft_model(model, config)
model.print_trainable_parameters()
```

Output: trainable params: 4194304 || all params: 6742609920 || trainable%: 0.06220594176090199

```
model = SentimentClassifier(model, learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)
```

HFValidationError: Repo id must use alphanumeric chars or '-', '_', '.', '--' and '..' are forbidden, '-' and '.'
cannot start or end the name, max length is 96: 'PeftModelForCausalLM(
(base_model): LoraModel(
(model): LlamaForCausalLM(
(model): LlamaModel(
(embed_tokens): Embedding(32000, 4096, padding_idx=31999)
(layers): ModuleList(
(0-31): 32 x LlamaDecoderLayer(
(self_attn): LlamaAttention(
(q_proj): Linear8bitLt(
in_features=4096, out_features=4096, bias=False

I was trying to finetune the LLaMA 7B model using pytorch Lightning framework. But unable to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Pytorch Lightning you can use LlamaForSequenceClassification for doing classification task.